# Use list of string expressions as join condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list with strings as its elements.

```python
list_elem = ['df1.x1 == df2.p1', 'df1.x2 == df2.p2']
```

I would like to change that list to something like this.

```python
list_new = [ df1.x1 == df2.p1, df1.x2 == df2.p2 ]
```

I need this because i have to run a join with a parametric input given in the form of a list.

```python
df = df1.join(df2,list_new,"inner")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can achieve the desired result using [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df1.alias('df1').join(
    df2.alias('df2'),
    on=expr(" AND ".join(list_elem )),
    how="inner"
)
```

The line `" AND ".join(list_elem )` will join the elements in your list with the word `"AND"` in between.

```python
print(" AND ".join(list_elem ))
#df1.x1 == df2.p1 AND df1.x2 == df2.p2
```